# What is the difference between precision@k and MAP in statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, precision

I have seen the two metrics: precision@k and Mean Average Precision (MAP) that are been used to evaluate ranking positions. However, I couldn't find any useful documents that discusses the pros and cons of each method. What is the most effective method to use?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.